# Pyspark convert a Column containing strings into list of strings and save it into the same column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe with two columns.
example :

```
Col1 | Col2 
 001 | This is the first string
 002 | This is the second string.
```

I want to do an operation which converts the Dataframe column Col2 into thee following format -

```
Col1 | Col2
001  | ["This", "is", "the", "first", "string" ] 
002  | ["This", "is", "the", "second", "string" ]
```

Is there a built in functions that can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run `split` function

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


df = df.withColumn('Col2', f.split('Col2', ' '))
```